# can you explain single source shortest path distances? (graph algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

i know that Dijkstra algorithm is single source, but is Breadth first search algorithm single source also? i know that BFS goes through all the neighboring nodes so that might not be a single source.

thanks

Comment: What does wikipedia say? After reading the relevant articles, starting with [the shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), are there any *specific* questions?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, BFS is single source. However, BFS and Dijkstra's algorithm have different intended uses, Dijkstra's is for weighted graphs and BFS is for non-weighted graphs.

Note that this kind of question is discouraged on SO since it is very general and is extremely easily searchable.